# Set ListString value in a Word document using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, document

If I have a list in word, numbered in the following way:

```
a. This is the content   
   This is the rest of it
```

How do I set a different value to the 'numbering'?
For an example - To start with 'C':

```
C. This is the content   
   This is the rest of it
```

Comment: Is it possible to use **Range.FormattedText** only without the list numbering?